# Help identifying tantalum capacitor without EIA capacitance markings

Tags: capacitor, repair, tantalum

I purchased some Samsung PM953 NVMe SSDs from an eBay seller.

Unfortunately one of the SSDs has failed power loss protection capacitors and while functional, operates in a fail-safe mode at severely reduced performance barely faster than a traditional hard drive.

The markings on the tantalum capacitors do not appear to follow the standardized labeling for voltage/capacitance. Given that the SSD is from Samsung, I don't believe these are knockoff parts, maybe just a capacitor manufactured by Samsung themselves.

The top line on the capacitor is always 150, and the bottom line is either: C6O, C63, or C68.

The dimensions are (LxWxH): 7x4x3mm, which I think corresponds to an EIA 7343 package.

I measured with my multi-meter and it appears there is 12V across the capacitor. But my multimeter is RMS so I don't know if that's the true voltage or if there is a switching frequency at play here impacting my measurement.

I would appreciate it if someone could decipher what these markings mean so I can order replacement capacitors.

[image: Samsung PM953 PLP tantalum capacitors]

Comment: Are you sure these are tantalum? Tantalum capacitors are a bit strange to see in modern devices, as either low-ESR aluminum electrolytics or MLCCs are usually a better option.

Comment: Tantalums tend to offer more capacity per volume than aluminum elec.  I had one of those little brick computers by Byte, that used similar caps.  Most likely these are Tantalum Polymer.

Comment: They look like Panasonic Tantalum Polymer, but I can't find the **C60** code. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/6TPE150MF/P123515DKR-ND/8827097

Comment: @Hearth - We use tantalums all the time in our mil/aero/space designs.

Comment: @SteveSh Fair enough! I haven't had to work in highly space/weight-constrained environments like that, so that particular advantage didn't occur to me.

Comment: @Aaron: it looks like you're right, the Panasonic TDC series datasheet describes exactly the markings present on the capacitors: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/16TDC150MYF/10-16TDC150MYFCT-ND/10644071

The D size has the capacitance written in the first row (150uF), then the voltage (C=16V, D=20V) followed by the lot number, which would explain why I see a mix of C63 and C68 on another SSD.